# the superclass "javax.servlet.httpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have get a problem when I create a new web project in the eclipse.
There show 'the superclass "javax.servlet.httpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path'.
I have find solution on the Internet, but that not work.
The solution is Project Properties-> Java Build Path-> Add Library -> Select "Server Runtime" from the list-> Next->Select "Apache Tomcat"-> Finish.
Is there anybody can give me other solution? Thanks very much.
My OS is macOS,tomcat is 9.0.0.M9,jdk is 1.8.0_101,the eclipse is jee-neon.

Comment: Maybe typo? "javax.servlet.httpServlet" or "javax.servlet.HttpServlet"

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry I can't understand you meaning, I just start learn the JSP. I have change the tomcat 8, and there is no problem with the project, I don't know why.Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: If you typed httpServlet with lowercase 'h', try correcting it with uppercase 'H', just like "HttpServlet"

Comment: Specifically, if you have a page directive in your JSP referencing that type as its superclass. Java is a case sensitive language.

Answer (score 11):

I have solved the problem by doing the following,

Actually i got this error, my scenario was..

I was using the APACHE TOMCAT SERVER VERSION 8.0, but the project i downloaded was using APACHE TOMCAT VERSION 7.0 it seems, so i changed it to version 8.

How was did was:

1. right Click on the Project properties.
2. In the Left menu, we can see the Java Build Path
3. Select the Library tab, and add the new Library.
4. In the Library Type, select the Server Run time, then click next and Finish will solve the problem.

All the Best

Answer (score 0):

I tried above steps and still errors were there in JSP even runtime libraries were configured properly. I'm using java 8 and tomcat 8. So I unchecked "validate jsp fragments" under project properties > validation > jsp syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With using Eclipse:

```
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600
```

I solved the Tomcat Server Library import as follows:

1. Right Click on the `Project properties`.
2. In the Left menu, we can see the `Java Build Path`.
3. Select the `Libraries` tab, and `Add Library` button.
4. In the `Add Library` window, select the `Server Runtime` in the list.
5. Click on `Next` button, Select the item `Apache Tomcat` mentioned with version in the list, and click on `Finish` button.

Wish it makes smile on your face!

Answer (score 0):

I have get a problem when I create a new web project in the eclipse.
There show 'the superclass "javax.servlet.httpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path'.
I have find solution on the Internet, but that not work.
The solution is Project Properties-> Java Build Path-> Add Library -> Select "Server Runtime" from the list-> Next->Select "Apache Tomcat"-> Finish.

If you work tomcat10 this solution maybe didn't worked for you.
My solution is going to instead tomcat10 to tomcat9.And I solve it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM-eWX102LQ this video can help you.